# How can I hide the shafts of matplotlib.quiver()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to hide the shaft of the arrows plotted by [matplotlib.pyplot.quiver()](https://tacaswell.github.io/matplotlib/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html). There seems to be no parameter to completely remove the shafts, as the arrow head sizes are proportional to the shaft sizes.

How can I remove or hide the shafts, so the arrowhead is the only visible component?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
u = v = 2
plt.quiver(0, 0, u, v, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.axis([-u-1, u+1, v-1, v+1])
```

[image: snippet output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to set the arrowhead size `headaxislength` and `headlength` such that the head completely covers the shaft. The lengths here are proportional to 'xy', the vector lengths, so we have to scale `1. / width` (the inverse proportionality) by the vector length, `np.sqrt(u**2 + v**2)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
u = v = 2
length = np.sqrt(u**2 + v**2)
width=0.005
hal = hl = 1. / width * length
plt.quiver(0, 0, u, v, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1, 
           headwidth=hl,
           headaxislength=hal,
           headlength=hl,
           width=width)
plt.axis([-2, u+1, -2, v+1])
```

[image]