# differing properties (transparency and color) between arrow head and shaft in quiver

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know how to set colours for arrows using quiver in matplotlib as per the example below, and the code allows a good degree of flexibility concerning the size, length and width of the arrow head, but is there the possibility to change other properties separately?  I specifically would like to be able to set the arrow head color and transparency different from that of the shaft

My example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
x=np.array([0,1,3,4])
y=np.array([2,4,0,1])
ax.quiver(x[:-1],y[:-1],x[1:]-x[:-1],y[1:]-y[:-1], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1,linewidth=1,color="red")
```

Produces standard red arrows, e.g.
[image]

can I make the shaft transparent with alpha while leaving the head untouched? ...and also give it a different colour? Or is there an alternative to quiver I should be looking at ?  I presume quiver is built around the arrow command, [but in the arrow documentation I can't see any options to separately specify the arrow head color or other properties](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html), only the size and appearance.

Comment: If I can draw each quiver separately, I can specify the transparency for each. `Q=ax.quiver(...);Q.set_alpha(0.5)`

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no way with matplotlib's built in functions to do this. I don't see why this couldn't be a feature, as you've rightly said you can change the arrow head size etc.. A possible solution would be to create your own function which draws the shaft and arrow head which would mean you have control over the colour, sort of similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163796/using-colormap-with-annotate-arrow-in-matplotlib), but I suspect it would require quite a lot of work

Comment: @DavidG, indeed I was thinking that this might be the case.  I'm trying to decide if it would help the clarity of my (very noisy) phase diagram enough to warrant the investment of time, hence my hope for something built in. I'll try the function out though that you point to if not, thanks for the link and tips.

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks, but the question is how to have a different property for the head and the shaft of a given arrow. Maybe I should update the example to a single arrow to avoid confusion.

Comment: I've just come across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201631/how-can-i-hide-the-shafts-of-matplotlib-quiver) which shows how to adjust a quiver plot so it looks like only the head is showing. This could mean that you can plot 2 quiver plots, one with just the shaft (`headlength` etc. set to 0), then plot another one as described in the post. Then you could change properties of both. This could be an easier option then drawing all the arrows yourself